# Who pays royalties to whom for the patents that form 802.11 standard

Tags: wifi, compliance, legal, 802.11

This is my first question here and it‘s not even electronics related. Shame on me!

I think it's a very important question to engineers like me who think about the idea of commercializing a device with a IEEE 802.11 based wireless interface.

In the WiFi world there are several entities involved:

- IEEE 802.11 standard. Which is based on a lot of patents from different companies/universities/inventors
- WiFi alliance that cares about compatibility between
  WiFi products and promotes WiFi as a technology
- Chipset vendors like Qualcomm, Intel, Broadcom, Mediatek who design a chip that works according to 802.11 standard
- 802.11 patent licensing programs from companies like Sisvel who charge around 25 Cent per WiFi device.

But there remains one specific question …

Who is responsible to pay royalties to whom when a Wifi product is designed, produced and put on the market? I always thought those royalties are covered at the time you buy a WiFi chipset from a company like Qualcomm.

But I no longer believe it’s so simple. Because then there would be no licensing program from companies like Sisvel.

Comment: Normally anybody who supplies IP that Broadcom puts in the chips would have an arrangement with Broadcom to collect the fee, possibly on a per-chip basis. The end customer who buys the Broadcom chip would not pay. I think people who contribute to the standard are not supposed to insert patented technology. There is some sense that major technology standards should not be encumbered by patents.  I could be wrong about that. The WiFi alliance probably guards WiFi logos and such to prevent people from advertising WiFi compatibility unless they are alliance members or alliance tested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question, not a design question.

Comment: I tried to update the question to make it less opionion-based. But I think it's the topic itself that is the culprit. Nobody really has a definitive answer to this complex topic and I don't know how to ask more specific. It might just be the wrong place for such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will use WiFi and 802.11 interchangeably for the sake of this question.

In the context of this question, that's an extremely confusing idea: Wifi is a trademark, and protected by additional laws and licensing requirements. Let's not do that.

> But it‘s a very important question to all those makers

By how I'd define "maker": no it isn't, because patents only affect *commercial* application of technology to begin with. If your application is not commercial, a patent can't stop you from using some method or device.

> and engineers out there working on IEEE 802.11 enabled products

Yes, but notice that you are **not** working on an IEEE 802.11 device itself - you literally buy the device as module. Therefore, the party building that module commercially has had to have a patent license (if there were any to acquired). They will have negotiated a license with every patent holder that allows them to sell products that their customers can freely use. Exactly the same as if you went to a store and bought a USB WLAN controller or WLAN router. You, as the customer, pay for someone else to already have acquired all the licenses needed.

This changes when you start actually implementing IEEE 802.11 technology.

> I always thought those royalties are covered at the time you buy a WiFi chipset from a company like Qualcomm.

*You* will never by a chipset from Qualcomm, they're not known for dealing with small quantity buyers (and "small" in terms of Qualcomm...). So, there'd be yet another module producer / middleman.

Even if you buy from a different entity, say Espressif, it's fair to assume you acquire licenses for all you need.

> Who is responsible to pay royalties to whom when a Wifi product is designed, produced and put on the market?

Whoever applies the patent commercially. So, that would be the producer of the Wifi module as well as who takes that module and uses it in their product.

However, you'll find that the IEEE 802 standards committee will not accept *essential patents*¹ unless you sign a letter stating that you'll license the patent to non-discriminately anyone, at reasonable rates, under fair conditions (FRAND, if you're looking for a term to google), and these usually involve a transitive license, so that only one party in that chain needs to license that patent themselves.

Members of the standardization committee need to disclose any patent they know of (their own, but also others') that would be required to implement the standard in creation. That way, they can't "sneak" a patent into a widely adopted standard and later demand arbitrarily much for a license to use, or kill their competition by refusing to license.

Such a "letter of assurance" can be found [here](https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/governance/patcom/custom-loa-802_11ax-NEC-28Jan2021.pdf).

> Who is responsible to pay royalties to **whom**

There's an excel list for that kind of thing, for each of their standards groups, at IEEE:

https://standards.ieee.org/about/sasb/patcom/patents.html

---

¹ "essential" means that you can't implement the standard without applying that patent

Comment: Your answer was helpful in the sense that it provides some important insights on how IEEE standards deal with patents. I also used your feedback to make some improvements on my question like "maker vs engineer" and "WiFi vs 802.11".